# Requests library - get TLS version used

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

When using the Python Requests library how can I determine which version of TLS was used?

Answer (score 3):

You first need to determine `SSL` version to get `TLS` version. `TLS` stack will use the best version available automatically

```
import ssl
print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2016'
```

Also, which version of `TLS` support you want depends on your `SSL` version.

[Check this nice way](https://gist.github.com/Integralist/2718a4eb51b00a7a4138fd182566c53b) to determine `TLS` version using python

Comment: Thank you for the comment. What if the server has a lower version than my max? Then I can't know until the request is made what version will be used.

Comment: Documentation of requests shows you can force client to use specific TLS version http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version

Comment: This is an option, but I am currently trying to see if I can just log it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32311849/1617748) there is no way to get the socket information (which holds the TLS information as far as I understand) after a `requests` request is executed (unless it is a streaming request).

As [Harry_pb points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50473663/1617748), your SSL version and the server's TLS version determines the TLS version used in the connection.

The socket library docs shows how to [get a socket's TLS version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#socket-creation):

```
import socket
import ssl

hostname = 'www.python.org'
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        print(ssock.version())
```